# How to find a point on linestring and in a range of 10 meter

Tags: point, spatial-database, mysql, linestring

i have a linestring which is show in diagram and i have a point which is some time on the linestring or out of linestring  but in range which is red line and some time its is out of range so how can i find when its on route and out of route in mysql spatial index

[image]

MY project is this as you can see bus no 26 is out off route so how can i get the bus is out off route

[image]

i think there is two things to do this

1. convert linestring into a polygon with range and find point in a polygon.
2. Point convert into polygon and check linestring is intersect the polygon.

so tell how can i do that

my database structure is

```
'id', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'route_name', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'from_id', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'to_id', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'line_string', 'geometry', 'NO', 'MUL', NULL, ''
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. This is a fairly standard (buffer linestring, then do point in polygon) operation. Does it have to be mysql? What have you already tried?

Comment: yes i tried this but i am stuck there because this is new for me.and i am use mysql to do this

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what you've already done. Can you create the buffer for your linestring as a polygon geometry (say in another table)? Do you know how to do a point in polygon test?

Comment: i m create a table which is store my linestring and my line string is longitude and latitude 

no i dont know about buffer

Comment: can i convert a linestring to polygon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the polygon using [Buffer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_buffer).

Note that the distance is in the units of the coordinate reference system you're using (which is probably degrees since you said its latitude and longitude). So if you want a 10 metre buffer, you probably need to project it (or be willing to accept some inaccuracy in the buffer size if you just want to convert 10 metres to degrees). You can't do the projection inside mysql - it isn't that smart. Other databases (e.g. spatialite or postgis) can do this with ST_Transform. The inaccuracy in trying to do it in degrees will depend on how many degrees of latitude vs degrees of longitude 10m is for your working location.

Once you have that, you can do [ST_Disjoint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-disjoint) to select any points that aren't within a polygon.

Comment: ok postgis have lots of dependency issue so have to try spatialite

Comment: You could also do the buffering with GDAL (https://github.com/csterling/ogrTools/blob/master/buffer.py) or many other tools, like QGIS.

Comment: can i do this on GRASS GIS